# Rails follow href path instead of redirect_to in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app I have a modal that pops up for anytime a student is clicked to be edited. Before it redirects to the edit page, the user must provide a rationale and name for the edit being made (this information is saved in another database). However, on the confirm button in the modal I assign the href value throuh jQuery and want the page to be redirected there upon click, but it follows the path defined in the rationale_controller.rb redirect_to clause. Is there a way I can have it follow the HREF attribute instead?

All help is appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:**

Modal button: `<button class="btn btn-warning" id="editStudentConfirmBtn">Edit</button>`

JS to assign HREF:

```
var kid_id = $(this).data('id');
$("#editStudentConfirmBtn").attr("href", "/kids/" + kid_id + "/edit");
```

Default rational_controller.rb setting:

```
def create
@rationale = Rationale.new(rationale_params)
@rationale.user = current_user
respond_to do |format|
  if @rationale.save
    format.html { redirect_to @rationale, notice: 'Rationale was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @rationale }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @rationale.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end

**EDIT 2:**

[Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm7Ud.png)

Comment: Can you share your code as to we can see what you have tried to so far?

Comment: You set href on what?

Comment: The simplest solution may be to pass the needed url in params and redirect to that url in the controller.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev The href is on the actual button in the modal

Comment: I have made edits to better explain the question

Comment: You're talking about `edit` action but you've posted the code for `create` action. Your question is hard to understand. Can you share the code the modal code? And anything that will help others understand your question better. Also please fix the typos in your question.

Comment: Buttons don't have a href attribute. Links do.

Comment: @ArunKumar there are 2 different models here, one is `Kid` and one is `Rationale`. The _edit_ button should go to the _edit_ page for the `Kid` object but at the same time it should submit the form to the `Rationale` DB.

Comment: @ArunKumar I added a screenshot for better intuition

Comment: @AlvinLau I think you didn't understand what I asked for. Why did you post the code for `create` action. What has it to do with `edit` action? Please post your `edit` action code. And to change the `href` attribute's value, you need a `anchor` tag. You can display the `anchor` tag as a button using bootstrap class `btn`

Comment: @ArunKumar once we hit `edit` it is actually targeting the `create` action for `Rationale`, which is what I am trying to redirect to the href I assign to the `btn` with the jQuery code posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution required an AJAX call that would redirect the page to a specified location after the `create` action was executed.

I had to change the controller for `Rationale` as follows:

```
def create
   @rationale = Rationale.new(rationale_params)
   @rationale.user = current_user
   respond_to do |format|
      if @rationale.save
        format.html { render :nothing => true }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @rationale }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @rationale.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
 end
```

And changed the JS as follows instead of assigning a href to the button using jQuery I just used an AJAX call to redirect the page automatically:

```
$('#editStudentConfirmBtn').click(function(){
        $.ajax({
          success: function(result) {
            location.href = '/kids/' + kid_id + '/edit'
          }
      });
    });
```